# passing var into objective c block

Tags: ios, location, reverse-geocoding

I'm using the reverse geocoder and I want to save info into a SQLite database but I need the latitude and longitude set by the user but it's not being passed.
I've got two doubles var called latitude and longitude and when I execute this code below, it uses "random" doubles:

```
CLLocation *locate = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude];

    CLGeocoder *geoCoderCL = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geoCoderCL reverseGeocodeLocation: locate completionHandler: 
     ^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

         CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

         Controller *mController = [[Controller alloc] init];
         MyObject *newposition = [[Meeting alloc]init];
         [newposition setLatitude:latitude];
         [newposition setLongitude:longitude];
         [newposition setMName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",placemark.thoroughfare,placemark.subThoroughfare]];
         NSLog(@"%@ %@",placemark.thoroughfare,placemark.subThoroughfare);
         [mController createRecentPoint:newposition];
         [mController release];
         [newposition release];

     }];
```

How is supposed to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following to derive the latitude and longitude from a `CLPlacemark` object.

```
CLLocationDegrees latitude = placemark.location.coordinate.latitude;
CLLocationDegrees longitude = placemark.location.coordinate.longitude;
```

`location` is a `CLLocation` object. `coordinate` is a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` struct and `latitude` and `longitude` are `CLLocationDegrees` (which is just a typdef'd `double`).